# where condition in case statement - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I need to show where condition based on a transaction type(expense,loan,deposit etc).
if transaction type is not equal to 'Loan' then show the where condition(where amount>1000).
if transaction type is 'Loan' then there is no need for where condition.
The problem is For Transaction type 'Loan' the amount is null.

Here is my Query..But I am getting error. Help me what mistake I am doing here.
This query is part of a bigger Dynamic SQL.

```
@SQL=@SQL+' case when TransactionType=''Loan'' then ''null'' else  TotalAmount > ' + @amount + ' end '
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a case statement.

`where TransactionType = 'Loan' or (TransactionType <> 'Loan' and TotalAmount > @amount)`

Also not sure if you need `TransactionType <> 'Loan'` based on the limited query given.

Comment: I think we need  case statement because for loans(transtype) amount is null.

Comment: In the where clause above it ignores amount for loans so it doesn't matter if it's null.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. I dont need case statement. Thanks for your help.